# What do authuser=0, etc., mean in a Google URL?

Tags: address-bar

I noticed google.com has this at the end,

https://www.google.com/**webhp?hl=en&tab=ww&authuser=0**

It isn't a virus is it?

This was on chrome

I also noticed another similar to that on internet explorer

https://www.google.co.uk/**webhp?hl=en&tab=ww**

Answer (score 11):

No, this is not a virus.

The `authuser` parameter is a way of controlling which Google account you're using (only useful if you have multiple accounts logged in).

From [this blog post](http://blog.metamatt.com/blog/2013/01/31/google-default-account-for-multiple-sign-in/):

> What’s controlling its choice? It turns out it’s the order you sign
>   into the accounts. If you look closely at the URLs, either by mousing
>   over the links in the account switcher or by looking at the URL you
>   end up at for gmail but not for docs5, you’ll see an “authuser” or “u”
>   parameter which is a low-valued integer. It starts at 0 for the first
>   account you sign into, and counts up from there as you sign into
>   additional accounts.
>
> If you navigate directly to docs.google.com (or mail.google.com, etc),
>   you’ll get the account currently associated as authuser 0, which is
>   the first account you signed into.

I'm unsure what `tab` does, but `hl` changes the language (but not search localisation) - try changing `hl=en` to `hl=de` and see what happens ([reference](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en)).

Comment: I see it's just that the webhp part got my alarm bells ringing

Comment: That would be the "web-search home page". `imghp` is the "image search home page" at a guess. Definitely nothing untoward though.

Comment: but this also appeared on another browser on my laptop

Comment: Again, these are Google-specific URL strings. It's like going to mysite.com/page1 and mysite.com/page2. They will persist across any permutation of browser, O/S and computer, because they are how Google's website URLs are structured.